# Find specific elements in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of items that looks, for instance, like this:

```
[el, el, *el*, TARGET, TARGET, TARGET, *el*, el, el, el]
```

I can't find a way to get previous and subsequent elements relative to the TARGET sequence, i.e both `*el*`. Number of TARGET element in sequence may vary but the sequence is always concrete i.e `TARGET, el, TARGET` does not happen. I have access to lodash methods, too, but I couldn't find the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: You can do a better explanation ?

Comment: A combination of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)?

Comment: show the array with real values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`:

```js
var arr = ['el', 'el', '*el*', 'TARGET', 'TARGET', 'TARGET', '*el*', 'el', 'el'];

var first = arr[arr.indexOf('TARGET') - 1];
var second = arr[arr.lastIndexOf('TARGET') + 1];

document.write(first + '<br/>');
document.write(second);
```

Comment: @dandavis the question specifically says that does not happen.